# using Optional and lambdas in Java

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

I was writing code using Optional and lambdas in Java and was wondering what would be the best approach in the following situation:

```java
public Optional<BObject> readIndexMaybe(String ref) {
    try {
        return Optional.ofNullable(index.read(ref)).map(BObjectBuilder::build);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read index of ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

public Optional<BObject> readMaybe(String ref) {
    Optional<BObject> bObject = readIndexMaybe(ref);
    return bObject.flatMap(boMaybe -> {                <---- HERE
        try {
            LOGGER.debug(String.format("Object read: %s", ref));
            BObject obj = new BObjectBuilder(boMaybe).stream(loadDocumentStream(boMaybe)).build();
            return Optional.of(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read file with ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    });
}
```

Is it better to use a lambda function that returns an `Optional<BObject>` and then use `flatMap` over it to receive `Optional<BObject>` as a return type, or would it be better to return `null` inside the lambda and then just use `map`:

```java
public Optional<BObject> readIndexMaybe(String ref) {
   try {
       return Optional.ofNullable(index.read(ref)).map(BObjectBuilder::build);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read index of ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
   }
   return Optional.empty();
}

public Optional<BObject> readMaybe(String ref) {
   Optional<BObject> bObject = readIndexMaybe(ref);
   return bObject.map(boMaybe -> {              <--- HERE
       try {
           LOGGER.debug(String.format("Object read: %s", ref));
           return new BObjectBuilder(boMaybe).stream(loadDocumentStream(boMaybe)).build();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read file with ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
       }

       return null;
   });
}
```

The first approach seems slightly better to me, as I could potentially reuse the lambda function elsewhere and it wouldn't return `null` but `Optional`. But is it worth it as long as I'm only using it in one place?

Comment: I think this is somewhat opinion-based (i.e. off-topic). I would prefer the former because I try to avoid using the `null` keyword unless I absolutely have to. However the latter is more concise.

Comment: I would suggest not using optional in this case as it just complicates everything.

Comment: You could rethrow the Exception wrapped in an `UncheckedIOException` and then catch it outside of the lambda and return an empty optional.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice, I'd recommend writing functions that return `Optional` instead of null if no-result is a normal and expected outcome. Thus you'd use `flatMap` to call such functions. The `map` operation is useful for functions that always return a valid result. It does also convert a null return into an empty `Optional`, which is mainly useful when you need to adapt to null-returning code that you can't change.

The usual recommendation is to extract a method instead of using a multi-line statement lambda. Then, use a simple lambda or method reference in the `flatMap` operation.

In addition, for the try/catch blocks, I'd recommend minimizing the code in the try-clause to only the code that can actually throw the exception you're catching, and do additional conversions outside the try-statement. In this case I assume that `index.read(ref)` and `loadDocumentStream(boMaybe)` are the statements that can throw `IOException`. Note that this means that a local variable needs to hold the temporary result, and that it's nullable. I think this is OK. The null handling is quite localized, and it allows you to consolidate the creation of the returned `Optional` into a single expression.

Finally, I recommend against using the suffix "maybe" for optionals. It's confusing, and in the example the lambda parameter `boMaybe` for `flatMap` operation is incorrect. That lambda is evaluated only when the value is present, so there's no "maybe" about it.

Applying all these recommendations gives the resulting code:

```
Optional<BObject> readIndex(String ref) {
    Index i = null;
    try {
        i = index.read(ref);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(/*...*/);
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(i).map(BObjectBuilder::build);
}

Optional<BObject> load(BObject bo) {
    DocStream docStream = null;
    try {
        LOGGER.debug(/*...*/);
        docStream = loadDocumentStream(bo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(/*...*/);
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(docStream)
                   .map(ds -> new BObjectBuilder(bo).stream(ds).build());
}

Optional<BObject> read(String ref) {
    return readIndex(ref).flatMap(bo -> load(bo)); // or this::load
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to provide a stable and safe api, which is why you're using `Optional`, though in your case it complicates stuff a bit, as you need to catch checked exceptions. I suggest this approach:

```
public Optional<BObject> readIndexMaybe(String ref) {
   try {
       return Optional.ofNullable(index.read(ref)).map(BObjectBuilder::build);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read index of ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
   }
   return Optional.empty();
}

public Optional<BObject> readMaybe(String ref) {
   Optional<BObject> bObject = readIndexMaybe(ref);
   if(!bObject.isPresent()){
      return bObject; // is same as Optional.empty()
   }
   BObject boMaybe = bObject.get();
   try {
      LOGGER.debug(String.format("Object read: %s", ref));
      boMaybe = new BObjectBuilder(boMaybe).stream(loadDocumentStream(boMaybe)).build();
      return Optional.of(boMaybe);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error(String.format("Could not read file with ref: %s, error: %s", ref, e));
      return Optional.empty();
   }
}
```

This is very similar to your map approach, but I think it is more clear, because you don't have the `try-catch` inside a lambda.